# Batch File to pull part of a file name

Tags: batch-file

I receive a certain file every month that I would like use to create a new directory on a server. for example the file I receive would look like:

201501Payments.done

I'd like to take the first 6 characters of the name to create a directory in a windows batch file. How can I specify those 6 characters and place it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window, execute in this window `set /?` (or alternatively `help set`) and read the help output into the window.

You can read about string substitution:

```
@echo off
set "FileName=201501Payments.done"
set "DirectoryName=%FileName:~0,6%"
echo Directory name is: %DirectoryName%
pause
```